# Does object creation overhead apply to structs?

Tags: c#, performance, object, struct, creation

I'm asking for a project in C#, but I assume this question applies to other languages as well. I've heard that massive object creation and destruction causes massive overhead and performance issues. I'm wondering if I can get around this by simply using structs instead of objects.

Comment: Object creation does incur some real costs -- you're enlisting the garbage collector; while gen 0 is pretty efficient, it's still not as efficient as passing a simple integer if that was the sum total of the data you are intending to pass around.  Generally speaking, structs are better (pretty much always assuming you're making them immutable) if the amount of data is very small (a handful of bytes).  Sometimes even larger, if the GC overhead makes it worth it.

Comment: If you want to know what the cost of a particular programming technique is then **use science**, not the opinions of strangers on the internet. Do you know you have a performance problem?  If you don't *know* that then *why are you trying to fix a problem you might not even have*, using techniques that probably won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some facts that you must now about `struct` and `class` in C# :

- A `struct` in C# is faster to create than a `class` since it's allocated on the stack and not on the heap
- `struct` is a value type, `class` is a reference type. So working with a reference type (passing it as parameter, copying it, ...) is much faster than working with the value type. see [Difference between struct and class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- `struct` fields are fast to access than `class` fields since they are allocated on the stack

Here is some facts about how the GC works in .Net :

- You can't have control on when the GC is triggered by the CLR, it can interrupts your program at any time (there is some options that you can use to tell the CLR that you are running a sensitive part of the code but it doesn't prevent the GC from running if memory is needed. see [GC Latency Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
- You can't have control on the time that the GC takes to do it's work
- When the GC is doing a full collection, it freezes all your program threads (depending on whether you are in gcConcurrent or gcServer mode see [gcServer mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165011%28v=office.11%29.aspx) ).

Knowing all of that and to be short, if you don't want your program to suffer from the GC work, you have to use reference types for objects that will live the longer in your program, and use value types for objects that will be used for a very short time and in a very localized scope.

Answer (score 5):

"Making struct instead of object" - as you term it (I suppose what you mean by *object* is *class*) would most likely be of little help since creating struct instance, due to struct's nature, will require you to refer it by value rather than by by reference - and this *may* (not always) make your memory use *heavier*

That being said, what you probably need is **Flyweight Design Pattern**

---

From https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight:

**Flyweight Design Pattern**

*Intent*

Use sharing to support large numbers of fine-grained objects efficiently.

The Motif GUI strategy of replacing heavy-weight widgets with light-weight gadgets.

*Problem*

Designing objects down to the lowest levels of system "granularity" provides optimal flexibility, but can be unacceptably expensive in terms of performance and memory usage.

*Discussion*

The Flyweight pattern describes how to share objects to allow their use at fine granularities without prohibitive cost. Each "flyweight" object is divided into two pieces: the state-dependent (extrinsic) part, and the state-independent (intrinsic) part. Intrinsic state is stored (shared) in the Flyweight object. Extrinsic state is stored or computed by client objects, and passed to the Flyweight when its operations are invoked.